# Setting and measuring risk profile target for retirement account

Tags: retirement, risk, asset-allocation, risk-management

I understand that as you age you want to slowly lower the risk profile of your retirement account, but how should I determine how much risk I should take on currently and how do I measure how much risk I am currently taking on? For example, I would think people that make more money can take on more risk because the minimum acceptable outcome would be a lower percent of their income than someone that makes less money.

Most commonly a single equity vs bond percent by age recommendation used generically for everyone, but wouldn't Large Cap vs Small Cap vs Emerging markets play into things? Along with how much money the person makes?

Comment: Do you know and understand how risk is often computed into a single value with investments?

Comment: Have you considered risk management?

Comment: @JBKing I understand the theory that a series of random normal variables when summed is another random normal variable, and how to do that on paper, but not really sure how to apply that to my portfolio and then how to establish a target. Also not sure how close to reality that theory is where stock isn't really normally distributed and with rebalancing or other real world complicationsn.

Comment: @Victor I'm not sure what you mean, my goal is to properly manage my risk, which is why I'm posting.  Do you mean considered talking to a professional risk manager?

Comment: No I don't mean talking to a professional risk manager. Take a stock as an example. Say you have $100k in capital. You may wish to limit the loss on each individual stock to 1% or $1000. Then you need to determine where you want to set your stop loss - this will then determine how many shares you buy to limit your loss to $1000 for that position. If the stock goes up you make profit, if it goes down you get out at your stop loss price and limit your losses.

Comment: @Victor as per some financial opinions, you do not put a stop loss on your investment, the intention is to hold it for long time, that is the primary reason close to retirement 70-80% of your money goes into bonds and about 30-20% into equity. The idea is that equity investment, irrespective of intermittent crash/fluctuations grow in the long term and therefore your stock investments should be in blue chips (which are at any point of time expensive). It is perhaps best to divide your money in bonds for day to day expenses and stocks for growth only.

Comment: @Ironluca - have you thought why so many people retire poor, maybe because they follow "...some financial opinions..." I know someone who is 69yo who has made a return of 7% in the last 2 months. They made 26% return last year. They did not do this by putting 70-80% into bonds. I personally made 19% last year and am up about 10% so far this year. I also have another smaller account which is up 177% over the last 2 years. The only time I would consider parking my money into bonds is when I am out of the market as it is freefalling 40%, 50% or more. Risk management is the key to success!

Comment: @Victor putting your question and your current comment together, it is clear that you are not talking about risk minimization of your retirement investments; what you are looking at is swing trading. My above comment comes from the retirement angle, if you follow the age wise allocation policy to bonds and stock, your aggregate holding would not be 70-80% on bond. I wish to highlight this. So, it is clear that you are OK with your fixed income and looking at playing the market. In this case perhaps you will not find a perfect model to optimize your risks, no one yet has ... cont ...

Comment: what you could do is analyze the returns over the past of the stocks that you are interested and look at the variance, that would give some indication of your downside potential. You could try and reduce volatility of your portfolio by spreading across blue chip, mid cap & small cap in mature, high growth stocks but there perhaps is no single model that can provide you with a number that you can surely say is your risk. As for the stop loss, there are many techniques you could use.

Comment: @Ironluca - I don't swing trade. I invest for the medium-long term (trend trade). When I get into a position I place a trailing stop and stay in it until the price starts dropping. If the price keeps moving up for 10 years I will stay in it for 10 years. But as soon as it drops to my trailing stop loss point I am out. I know my exact maximum loss on each position but let my profits run. I run a smaller account on margin with a tighter stop but also with profit targets. I don't day trade and spend no more than 5 hours/week. I am 45 and semi-retired and live of my property and share investments.

Comment: @Victor in relation to your above comments, to limit loss to $1000 on $100,000 position on one stock you shall have to buy (100K/price) no. of stocks but then your tolerance to downside is exactly 1% (ignoring brokerage). If the stock moves 1% intra-day, your stop loss is triggered, how does this situation help you to optimize risk? Stop losses are based on support/resistances and are not usually on absolute value In addition your strategy perhaps will have limitations while the market is falling Your entry will have to be very timed None of this actually help you to optimize risk,I an curious

Comment: @Ironluca - Firstly with an account of $100K I would not open one position of $100K and risk 1% on it. I meant that with an account of $100K I would risk 1% of that $100K ($1000) on any one position. I would use [Position Sizing](http://www.vantharp.com/tharp-concepts/position-sizing.asp) to work out how many share to buy in each position. Simply, if my risk on any one position is $1000 I would then set a stop price, say 10% on a price of $10, my stop price would be set at $9. We can then determine the shares to buy by dividing the risk $1000 by the stop $1 to get 1000 shares to buy.

Comment: @Ironluca - Secondly I would never buy into a falling market. As a trend follower I would only buy into a rising market. I would actually get fully out of a falling market similar to what we had in 2007/08. What I would do in a falling market is to take on short positions, which I have started doing this year with my smaller geared account. Also regarding setting stop prices, the larger your stop the smaller your position will be and the longer you will be in a position in general. Larger stops would generally be used with longer-term investing, whilst smaller stops with shorter-term trading.

Comment: @Victor with reference to your mode of taking position, I have put some thought, thought it may not warrent as a full answer, I shall detail the same as comment. They are a clutch of observations really and I shall detail them, give me a day or two - thanks

Comment: @Victor as mentioned, your method assumes 2 things from the onset, the price at which you will buy the shares and the stop loss (perhaps based on support/resistance etc.). So the position sizing is essentially 1000/diff(stop loss, purchase price). Now, the smaller the 'diff' in in absolute terms, more number of shares you will buy. Your stop loss hence becomes a absolute figure and not a %, so higher the prices go closer your trailing stop loss will become, at some point, your trailing stop loss will come within intra day volatility and you may get stopped out ... cont ...

Comment: In this scenario, will you be able to hold on to the investment past about 10%-15% gain? The matter that I see is that higher the prices go, closer your stop loss creeps up (since it is an absolute figure) and at some point you will hit intraday volatility and get stopped out, just wondering how the method will perform under this circumstance.

Comment: @Ironluca - 2 scenarios. 1st, if setting stops based on support levels then the stop would move up as a new support level is created. A trend is defined as higher highs and higher lows - the new support levels are these new lows. So if the price falls through a new support then the trend is over and so should the trade. 2nd, if setting stop on % of latest high, I would personally base this on the highest close not the highest intraday price. So to be stopped out the price has to fall by the % below the highest close. Using 15%-20%, if price falls that much - the trend would usually be over.

Comment: @Ironluca - and using a 15% stop from the highest close I have had gains above 40% with 56% so far my highest.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" amount of risk is subjective.  You are correct that a person's income, assets, and liabilities contribute to the capacity to take risk.  Some people are also more comfortable taking risk than others.

Time horizon is also important.  Some investments cannot be sold quickly, but might have higher expected returns to compensate.  Some university endowments invested heavily in illiquid assets based on this belief.  It worked well for awhile, but later struggled.  See this article for more on this.

You may also want to consider an asset/liability framework.  In this view, the present value of future expenses increases when interest rates decline.

You are correct that different types of equities and bonds have different amounts of risk.  High yield bonds have a much different risk profile than treasury bonds.  There are a number of ways to measure risk.  You could look at the portfolio historical standard deviation or maximum draw-down as potential measures.

The "correct" allocation also depends on your comfort with complexity.  For example, are you comfortable having a different allocation in your taxable account and retirement account? Are you willing to take the time to understand why the best portfolio might involve different assets in different accounts?

Health is also important.  Some people feel like can work into their 80's while others lose the ability to work much younger. If you have the option to work, you have a higher capacity for risk.

As you can see, the inputs for the "right" answer can be both unique to the individual and subjective.  The output isn't fully objective either.